# Trouble to find size of an Array & Output issue

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I'm implementing  **Binary search**. But I don't want to pass the size of an array as an argument  in the `binarySearch` function. I'm trying to find array size in function. I use `sizeof operator`, but the output of the binary search is wrong. when I try to pass the size of array as an argument then the output is fine. My question is why & what is the problem for calculating array size in function? is it possible to calculate array size in function?

Here is my approach:

```
code

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void binarySearch(int arr[], int value)
{
   int c = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
   
  //cout << c;
  int low = 0, high = c - 1, notFound = 1;

  while (low <= high)
  {
     int mid = (low + high) / 2;
     if (arr[mid] == value)
     {
        cout << "Found at index " << mid << endl;
        notFound = 0;
        break;
     }
     if (arr[mid] < value)
     {
        low = mid + 1;
     }
     else
     {
        high = mid - 1;
     }
   }

   if (notFound == 1)
   {
      cout << "Not Found" << endl;
   }
}
int main()
{
   int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 56, 88};
   int x = 3;
   binarySearch(arr, x);
   //cout << p << endl;
}
```

---

**output:**

```
 tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:5:22: warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'arr' will return size of 'int*' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
    int c = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
                      ^
tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:3:23: note: declared here
 void binarySearch(int arr[], int value)
                   ~~~~^~~~~
Not Found
```

**My expected Output:**

```
Found at index 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why & what is the problem for calculating array size in function

The problem is that `arr` is a pointer to an element of the array. The size of the pointer has nothing to do with the size of the array, which is why your attempted `sizeof(arr)` cannot work.

The warning message also explains this quite well.

> is it possible to calculate array size in function?

Given only a pointer to an element, it is generally<sup>1</sup> **not possible** to determine the size of the array. That is why you must pass the size as an argument.

Another approach which I prefer is to encapsulate the pointer and the length in a class. There is a standard class template for this purpose: `std::span`.

```
void binarySearch(std::span<int> arr, int value)
{
   int c = arr.size();
   ...


// call as in your example:
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 56, 88};
int x = 3;
binarySearch(arr, x);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There are techniques that allow this, but they have draw backs.

One technique is to choose one element value as a "terminator" aka "sentinel" which signifies the end of the array. That way, you can do a linear search for the terminator to determine the length. This is commonly used in C with strings, where the null terminator character terminates the string. This technique isn't an option if you cannot dedicate any of the values as a terminator. The other obvious drawback is the linear complexity of the size calculation which is asymptotically more expensive than the binary search that you're implementing

Answer (score 0):

There is a further possibility that you could use, but calling it with too many different array sized might cause code bloat.

```
template<std::size_t N>
void binarySearch(int arr[N], int value)
```

And then use `N` instead of `c`.